# Python: read multiple source txt files, copy by criteria into 1 output file

Tags: python, python-2.7

My objective is to read multiple txt source files in a folder (small size), then copy lines selected by criteria into one output txt file.
I can do this with 1 source file, but I have no output (empty) when I try to read multiple files and do the same.

With my SO research I wrote following code (no output):

```
import glob
# import re  --- taken out as 'overkill'

path = 'C:/Doc/version 1/Input*.txt'   # read source files in this folder with this name format
list_of_files=glob.glob(path)   

criteria = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF']   # select lines that start with criteria

#list_of_files = glob.glob('./Input*.txt')

with open("P_out.txt", "a") as f_out:
    for fileName in list_of_files:
        data_list = open( fileName, "r" ).readlines()
    for line in data_list:
        for letter in criteria:
            if line.startswith(letter): 
                f_out.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

Thank you for your help.

@abe and @ppperry: I'd like to particularly thank you for your earlier input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The errors:

1. Line #14 should look for lines in data_list, not fileName.
2. **"I can do this with 1 source file, but I have no output (empty) when I try to read multiple files and do the same."** Lines 14 through 17 should be indented or else the for loop that iterates over the list_of_files will only loop over the first file.
3. You did not even use lines 4 and 5, so why include them? They have no effect.

Here is your code fixed, with comments:

```
import glob
import re

#path = 'C:\Doc\version 1\Output*.txt'   # read all source files with this name format
#files=glob.glob(path)

criteria = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF']   # select lines that start with criteria

list_of_files = glob.glob('./Output*.txt')

with open("P_out.txt", "a") as f_out: #use "a" so you can keep the data from the last Output.txt
    for fileName in list_of_files:
        data_list = open( fileName, "r" ).readlines()
        #indenting the below will allow you to search through all files.
        for line in data_list: #Search data_list, not fileName
            for letter in criteria:
                if re.search(letter,line):
                    f_out.writelines('{}\n'.format(line))
                    #I recommend the \n so that the text does not get concatenated when moving from file to file. 

#Really? I promise with will not lie to you. 
#f_out.close()  # 'with' construction should close files, yet I make sure they close
```

For those who downvoted, why not include a comment to justify your judgment? Everything the OP requested has been satisfied. If you think you can further improve the answer, suggest an edit. Thank you.

Comment: Read the answer. @ppperry

Comment: My output is still empty. Is the possible issue that lines only appear in notepad++ but if read in notepad there are no lines, only one sequence of characters?

Comment: Did you copy and paste my code? Running it on my machine I get the correct output. Are you sure your Output*.txt's contain lines that start with AB, CD, EF?

Comment: Affirmative, source files with lines starting with [AB,CD,EF], yet no output. As I mentioned in my previous comment, in notepad++ my source files have lines, yet no lines in notepad.

Comment: NEVER use notepad when programming. It is terrible at encoding. Use anything EXCEPT notepad. @user1739581 I assume you see that my solution worked. Great.

Answer (score 2):

Problems with your code:

1. You have two duplicate variables `files` and `list_of_files` but only use the latter.
2. Every time you open a file, you override the variable `data_list`, which erases the contents of the previous file read.
3. When you search the file for matching lines, you use the variable `fileName` instead of `data_list`!

Places that could use simplification:

1. Using the `re` module is overkill for just finding out whether a string starts with another string. You can use `line.startswith(letter)`.

Comment: I would not call #4 a problem, but as you said, "overkill."